# Can an encryption key be discovered with the encoded string and string?

Tags: php, encryption

I am using the PHP `mcrypt_encrypt` function to encrypt an ID to be sent in a URL. For example: `/?id=encryptedstring` rather than `/?id=1`; this is to prevent users from guessing the next sequence.

Is it possible for a user to discover the encryption key if they have the encrypted string and the original value?

Comment: Depends on your encryption algorithm, and how long the key is. If you're simply doing `sha1($id)` or `md5($id)` to "encrypt", then it'd be trivial to check what `sha1($id+1)` is.

Comment: What would happen if someone guesses the next in sequence or any other valid identifier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encryption is not the right way to go here.

If you are worried about the user guessing the next sequence, consider giving each record a random, 10- or 20-digit ID from the start instead.

However, if you're protecting sensitive data, relying on un-guessable URLs is **not** sufficient security. URLs can be passed on, will be stored in the browser's history, will be visible in proxy and server logs, etc.

In that case, you need to implement an authorization system that allows users only to access the records they are allowed to access (e.g. by logging users in), so it doesn't matter whether they know the sequence.

Comment: Access control is authorization and not authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's possible. They can use a bruteforce attack and check their test encryption of the original, known value, with your encrypted string, and compare each possible key until they find one that generates the same encrypted string.

However, bruteforcing is very inefficient, so it's not likely they will discover your key.

See [this site](http://www.lockdown.co.uk/?pg=combi&s=articles) for more information about how long it would take a bruteforce attacker to discover your key.

Pekka gives a suggestion about simply denying access if the user doesn't have the correct permission to read the record, which you should definitely follow. "Security through obscurity is not security at all".

Comment: **very inefficient**?? Suppose you have a 128-bit key for AES encryption. Do you know how many possible option there are? 2^128 = ~10^38 ! Even if it takes you 1 millisec to test one option, it will take you (just did it for fun) 10790283070806014188970529154.99 years to check them all! :) Of course, cryptoanalysis is much more sophisticated than that, but you are talking about brute force

Comment: @davka Okay so maybe that was the understatement of the century, but my point is still valid that bruteforcing CAN find a given key. Just, chances are fewer than my suddenly learning how to fly this very instant

Answer (score 1):

If you are really worried about this, you can add [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) to your encryption.

Comment: Salting wouldn't be much different from the "key" that's already being used, and could be discovered in the same way.

Comment: then why does salting exist at all?  it adds another level of obscurity that must be brute forced.  anything can be cracked with enough time - making it harder (longer to crack) is what makes it more secure.  without the salt, a potential hacker couldn't say 'i want id 1000' and generate the hash

Answer (score 0):

usually it requires many more than one pair of clear+encrypted data in order to crack the encryption (i.e. to derive the key). This is if you use a decent encryption scheme, of course